# How to determine SSL cert expiration date from a PEM encoded certificate?

Tags: linux, bash, ssl, openssl, certificate

If I have the actual file and a Bash shell in Mac or Linux, how can I query the cert file for when it will expire?  Not a web site, but actually the certificate file itself, assuming I have the csr, key, pem and chain files.

Answer (score 1001, accepted):

With `openssl`:

```
openssl x509 -enddate -noout -in file.pem
```

The output is on the form:

```
notAfter=Nov  3 22:23:50 2014 GMT
```

Also see [MikeW's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31718838/1899640) for how to easily check whether the certificate has expired or not, or whether it will within a certain time period, without having to parse the date above.

Comment: You also have the `-startdate` and `-enddate` options built into the `x509` utility. They will save you the `grep`.

Comment: this also works if the file is not in pem format. works fine for server.crt

Answer (score 233):

If you just want to know whether the certificate has expired (or will do so within the next N seconds), the `-checkend <seconds>` option to `openssl x509` will tell you:

```
if openssl x509 -checkend 86400 -noout -in file.pem
then
  echo "Certificate is good for another day!"
else
  echo "Certificate has expired or will do so within 24 hours!"
  echo "(or is invalid/not found)"
fi
```

This saves having to do date/time comparisons yourself.

`openssl` will return an exit code of `0` (zero) if the certificate has not expired and will not do so for the next 86400 seconds, in the example above. If the certificate will have expired or has already done so - or some other error like an invalid/nonexistent file - the return code is `1`.

(Of course, it assumes the time/date is set correctly)

Be aware that older versions of openssl have a bug which means if the time specified in `checkend` is too large, 0 will always be returned (https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/6180).

Comment: To determine whether a certificate is currently expired, use a duration of zero seconds.  Omit the `-noout` option to see a helpful message using a single command without extra logic.  E.g., `openssl x509 -checkend 0 -in file.pem` will give the output "Certificate will expire" or "Certificate will not expire" indicating whether the certificate will expire in zero seconds.

Comment: Providing values > 30 years (922752000) to -checkend causes the option to behave unexpectedly (returns 0 even though certificate would expire during this timeframe).

Answer (score 47):

Here's my bash command line to list multiple certificates in order of their expiration, most recently expiring first.

```
for pem in /etc/ssl/certs/*.pem; do 
   printf '%s: %s\n' \
      "$(date --date="$(openssl x509 -enddate -noout -in "$pem"|cut -d= -f 2)" --iso-8601)" \
      "$pem"
done | sort
```

Sample output:

```
2015-12-16: /etc/ssl/certs/Staat_der_Nederlanden_Root_CA.pem
2016-03-22: /etc/ssl/certs/CA_Disig.pem
2016-08-14: /etc/ssl/certs/EBG_Elektronik_Sertifika_Hizmet_S.pem
```

Comment: Very nice! This is what I was after. Now I have an overview of the certificiates that I have to renew soon. Saved it as checkcerts.sh in my home folder so I can check it regularly. Next thing would be to have a CRON job to check every month and email the certificates that need renewal.

Comment: Very usefull thanks. I use this cronjob `0 7 * * 1 /path/to/cert.sh | mail -s "certbot" my@email.com`

Answer (score 29):

Command:

```
# cat {key_name} | openssl x509 -noout -enddate
Example: # cat tower.cert | openssl x509 -noout -enddate
```

Result:

```
notAfter=Dec  7 04:03:32 2023 GMT
```

Answer (score 16):

Here's a bash function which checks all your servers, assuming you're using DNS round-robin. Note that this requires GNU date and won't work on Mac OS

```
function check_certs () {
  if [ -z "$1" ]
  then
    echo "domain name missing"
    exit 1
  fi
  name="$1"
  shift

  now_epoch=$( date +%s )

  dig +noall +answer $name | while read _ _ _ _ ip;
  do
    echo -n "$ip:"
    expiry_date=$( echo | openssl s_client -showcerts -servername $name -connect $ip:443 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -inform pem -noout -enddate | cut -d "=" -f 2 )
    echo -n " $expiry_date";
    expiry_epoch=$( date -d "$expiry_date" +%s )
    expiry_days="$(( ($expiry_epoch - $now_epoch) / (3600 * 24) ))"
    echo "    $expiry_days days"
  done
}
```

Output example:

```
$ check_certs stackoverflow.com
151.101.1.69: Aug 14 12:00:00 2019 GMT    603 days
151.101.65.69: Aug 14 12:00:00 2019 GMT    603 days
151.101.129.69: Aug 14 12:00:00 2019 GMT    603 days
151.101.193.69: Aug 14 12:00:00 2019 GMT    603 days
```

Comment: surprisingly osx 10.13.4 runs your shell OK ( don't judge me I am only on osx today to push an app to app store ... booting back to linux shortly ;-)

Comment: @ScottStensland We are judging  :-P .  I use Mac a lot but Linux is really much better.

Comment: Thank you very much for that code snippit! What an annoying task :), I wish there was a unixtime timestamp flag for openssl.

Comment: For those of you on an alpine linux container, your `expiry_date` value will need to have the timezone name removed from the end of it. Add an additional `cut` to the end of the pipe to do this: `| cut -d ' ' -f 1-4`

Answer (score 16):

Same as accepted answer, But note that it works even with `.crt` file and not just `.pem` file, just in case if you are not able to find `.pem` file location.

```
openssl x509 -enddate -noout -in e71c8ea7fa97ad6c.crt
```

Result:

```
notAfter=Mar 29 06:15:00 2020 GMT
```

Comment: sidenote : the `-text` option shouldn't be placed together with `-enddate`

Answer (score 8):

One line checking on true/false if cert of domain will be expired in some time later(ex. 15 days):

```
openssl x509 -checkend $(( 24*3600*15 )) -noout -in <(openssl s_client -showcerts -connect my.domain.com:443 </dev/null 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -outform PEM)
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
  echo 'good'
else
  echo 'bad'
fi
```

Answer (score 3):

## Storing `openssl` fields into [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) variables

As this question is tagged [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), I often use *`UNIX EPOCH`* to store dates, this is useful for compute time left with `$EPOCHSECONDS` and format output via `printf '%(dateFmt)T` *bashism*:

```bash
{ read -r certStart;read -r certEnd;}< <(date -f <(cut -d = -f 2 <(
    openssl x509 -dates -noout -in "$file")) +%s)
```

Then

```bash
printf '%-6s %(%a %d %b %Y, %H %Z)T\n' start $certStart end $certEnd
```

```
start  Mon 01 Nov 2004, 17 UTC
end    Mon 01 Jan 2035, 05 UTC
```

Sample, listing content of `/etc/ssl/certs` and compute days left:

```bash
for file in /etc/ssl/certs/*pem;do
    { read -r certStart;read -r certEnd;}< <(
        date -f <(cut -d = -f 2 <(
            openssl x509 -dates -noout -in "$file")) +%s)
    printf "%(%d %b %Y %T)T - %(%d %b %Y %T)T: %6d %s\n" \
        $certStart $certEnd $(( (certEnd - EPOCHSECONDS)/86400 )) ${file##*/}
done
```

```
05 May 2011 09:37:37 - 31 Dec 2030 09:37:37:   3034 ACCVRAIZ1.pem
26 Oct 2010 08:38:03 - 26 Oct 2040 08:38:03:   6620 Buypass_Class_2_Root_CA.pem
19 Jan 2010 00:00:00 - 18 Jan 2038 23:59:59:   5609 COMODO_RSA_Certification_Authority.pem
13 Nov 2012 00:00:00 - 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07:   5609 GlobalSign_ECC_Root_CA_-_R4.pem
06 Apr 2001 07:29:40 - 06 Apr 2021 07:29:40:   -522 Sonera_Class_2_Root_CA.pem
29 Jun 2004 17:39:16 - 29 Jun 2034 17:39:16:   4310 Starfield_Class_2_CA.pem
04 Feb 2016 12:32:16 - 31 Dec 2029 17:23:16:   2669 TrustCor_RootCert_CA-1.pem
01 Nov 2004 17:14:04 - 01 Jan 2035 05:37:19:   4495 XRamp_Global_CA_Root.pem
...
```

#### More complete [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) x509 reading:

```bash
for file in /etc/ssl/certs/*pem;do
    mapfile -t x509 < <(openssl x509 -noout -dates -subject -in "$file")
    x509=("${x509[@]#*=}")
    mapfile -t dates < <(IFS=$'\n';date -f - <<<"${x509[*]::2}" +%s) 
    str="${x509[-1]}"
    declare -A Subj='([CN]="${file##*/}")'
    while [[ "$str" ]] ;do
        lhs=${str%%=*} rhs=${str#$lhs= } rhs=${rhs%% = *} rhs=${rhs%, *}
        Subj[${lhs// }]="$rhs"
        str=${str#"$lhs= $rhs"} str=${str#, }
    done
    printf "%(%d %b %Y %T)T - %(%d %b %Y %T)T: %s\n" \
        ${dates[@]} "${Subj[CN]}"
done
```

```
05 May 2011 09:37:37 - 31 Dec 2030 09:37:37:   3034 ACCVRAIZ1
26 Oct 2010 08:38:03 - 26 Oct 2040 08:38:03:   6620 Buypass Class 2 Root CA
19 Jan 2010 00:00:00 - 18 Jan 2038 23:59:59:   5609 COMODO RSA Certification Authority
13 Nov 2012 00:00:00 - 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07:   5609 GlobalSign
06 Apr 2001 07:29:40 - 06 Apr 2021 07:29:40:   -522 Sonera Class2 CA
29 Jun 2004 17:39:16 - 29 Jun 2034 17:39:16:   4310 Starfield_Class_2_CA.pem
04 Feb 2016 12:32:16 - 31 Dec 2029 17:23:16:   2669 TrustCor RootCert CA-1
01 Nov 2004 17:14:04 - 01 Jan 2035 05:37:19:   4495 XRamp Global Certification Authority
...
```

Note: Some certs don't have *`CN`* field in subject. For this I've initialized `$Subj` array by setting `CN` field to filename:
`declare -A Subj='([CN]="${file##*/}")'`

### Full [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) script

Sharing here a full bash script, showing all certificates from command line arguments, which could by *`file`*, *`domain name`* or *`IPv4 address`*. Will ouput *past days*, *days left*, *number of alternative domain*, and all *alts* in one (long) line:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

showCert() {
    local x509 dates lhs rhs str alts
    mapfile -t x509 < <(
        openssl x509 -noout -dates -subject -ext subjectAltName -in "$1")
    x509=("${x509[@]#*=}")
    mapfile -t dates < <(IFS=$'\n';date -f - <<<"${x509[*]::2}" +%s)
    str="${x509[2]}"
    local -A Subj;Subj[CN]="${file##*/}"
    while [[ -n "$str" ]]; do
        lhs=${str%%=*} rhs=${str#$lhs= } rhs=${rhs%% = *} rhs=${rhs%, *}
        Subj[${lhs// }]="$rhs"
        str=${str#"$lhs= $rhs"} str=${str#, }
    done
    read -ra alts <<<"${x509[4]//,}"
    alts=("${alts[@]#*:}")
    printf "  %(%d %b %Y %H:%M)T %(%d %b %Y %H:%M)T %6d %6d %-30s %3d %s\n" \
        "${dates[@]}" $(((dates[1]-EPOCHSECONDS)/86400)) $(((EPOCHSECONDS-
          dates[0])/86400)) "${Subj[CN]}" "${#alts[@]}" "${alts[*]}" 
}
```

```bash
checkIsIpv4() { # throw an error if not valid IPv4
    local _iPointer _i _a _vareq=()
    for _i ;do
        case $_i in *[^0-9.]* ) return 1 ;; esac
        read -ra _a <<<"${_i//./ }"
        [ ${#_a[@]} -eq 4 ] || return 1
        for _iPointer in "${_a[@]}" ;do
            (( _iPointer == ( _iPointer & 255 ) ))  || return 2
        done
    done
}
checkIsLabel() {
    ((${#1}<4 || ${#1}>253)) && return 1
    [[ -z ${1//[a-zA-Z0-9.-]} ]] || return 2
    [[ -z ${1//.} ]] && return 3
    set -- ${1//./ }
    (($#<2 )) && return 4
    :
}
```

```bash
printf '  %-17s %-17s %6s %6s %-30s %2s\n' Not\ before Not\ after left \
       past Common\ Name Alt 

for arg ;do
    if [ -f "$arg" ] ;then
        showCert "$arg"
    elif checkIsLabel "$arg" || checkIsIpv4 "$arg" ;then
        showCert <(openssl s_client -ign_eof -connect "$arg:443" \
                           <<<$'HEAD / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r' 2> /dev/null)
    else
        echo "Unknown argument: '$arg'."
    fi
done
```

#### Explanation

- function `showCert` create a ***array variable* `$x590`** with *dates*, *subject* and *alt names*.
- use `mapfile` and (only 1 fork to) `date` to convert **both** *start* **and** *end dates*.
- create an ***associative array variable* `$Subj`** for parsing *Subject* string (3rd line: `${x509[2]}`)
- split ***alternatives names*** into another ***array*: `$alts`**.
- the use `printf` to format and print each certificats showing

  - *start date*,
  - *end date*,
  - *days left*,
  - *days past*,
  - *common name*,
  - *number of alternative names* and
  - *alternative names*.

#### Usage sample:

```
./certShow.sh /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem www.example.com
  Not before        Not after           left   past Common Name                    Alt
  08 Sep 2021 16:49 06 Sep 2031 16:49   3277    372 hostname.local                   1 hostname.local
  14 Mar 2022 00:00 14 Mar 2023 23:59    179    186 www.example.org                  8 www.example.org example.net example.edu example.com example.org www.example.com www.example.edu www.example.net
```

Answer (score 2):

For MAC OSX (El Capitan)  This modification of Nicholas' example worked for me.

```
for pem in /path/to/certs/*.pem; do
    printf '%s: %s\n' \
        "$(date -jf "%b %e %H:%M:%S %Y %Z" "$(openssl x509 -enddate -noout -in "$pem"|cut -d= -f 2)" +"%Y-%m-%d")" \
    "$pem";
done | sort
```

Sample Output:

```
2014-12-19: /path/to/certs/MDM_Certificate.pem
2015-11-13: /path/to/certs/MDM_AirWatch_Certificate.pem
```

macOS didn't like the `--date=` or `--iso-8601` flags on my system.

Comment: How would you do this if you didn't have make the .pem files, but just had `.cer` certs you just made and downloaded from the Apple Dev site?

Answer (score 1):

If (for some reason) you want to use a GUI application in Linux, use `gcr-viewer` (in most distributions it is installed by the package `gcr` (otherwise in package `gcr-viewer`))

```
gcr-viewer file.pem
# or
gcr-viewer file.crt
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made a bash script related to the same to check if the certificate is expired or not. You can use the same if required.

**Script**

https://github.com/zeeshanjamal16/usefulScripts/blob/master/sslCertificateExpireCheck.sh

**ReadMe**

https://github.com/zeeshanjamal16/usefulScripts/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 0):

using `openssl`

here is a script to print out human readable text `cert-etime-check.sh`

```bash
#!/bin/bash

set -euo pipefail

### get a cert file
declare -r cert_file=${1:? error ... cert_file ?}

### start and end dates
declare -r beg_date=$(openssl x509 -noout -startdate -in $cert_file)
declare -r end_date=$(openssl x509 -noout -enddate -in $cert_file)

### subject and issuer
declare -r subject=$(openssl x509 -noout -subject -in $cert_file)
declare -r issuer=$(openssl x509 -noout -issuer -in $cert_file)

### calculate days gone and left
declare -ir beg_sec=$(date --date="${beg_date##*=}" +%s)
declare -ir end_sec=$(date --date="${end_date##*=}" +%s)
declare -ir now_sec=$(date +%s)

declare -ir day_gone=$(( $((now_sec - beg_sec)) / 86400))
declare -ir day_left=$(( $((end_sec - now_sec)) / 86400))

### print result
date --date="${beg_date##*=}" +"beg: %F-%A (gone: $day_gone)"
date --date="${end_date##*=}" +"end: %F-%A (left: $day_left)"
echo sum: $((day_gone + $day_left))
echo sub: ${subject##* = }
echo iss: ${issuer##* = }
echo
date +"now: %F-%A"
```

usage: `./cert-etime-check.sh cert.pem`

output:

```
beg: 2024-03-04-Monday (gone: 26)
end: 2024-06-02-Sunday (left: 63)
sum: 89
sub: ******.***
iss: R3

now: 2024-03-31-Sunday
```