# SSL exception invoking a rest api from Java

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, java-security

I see SSL exception while invoking a rest api using Jersey API client library.
This used to work fine till few days ago. Based on the exception, I understand it is certificate expiry related. 
However I am not sure if the client machine needs to have the certificate (if any) upgraded or the API implementation server needs to upgrade. 
 Code I use to call the API is mentioned below. I verified the ssl certs on my machine using [How to determine SSL cert expiration date from a PEM encoded certificate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21297853/how-to-determine-ssl-cert-expiration-date-from-a-pem-encoded-certificate) and I could not find any expired certificates.

```
 
com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: timestamp check failed
    at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:151)
```

```java
Client client = Client.create(JerseyJacksonConfigFactory.getConfig());
this.resource = client.resource(baseUrl);
resource.path("foo").entity(barEntity).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).put();
```

Comment: Connect to the server address and port with a browser.  If the browser doesn't show you any issues with the SSL cert then it's the client side.

Comment: @stdunbar - Browser too prompts untrusted connection. So I believe this is from the API implementation side. Thanks. If you add it as answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Wich jdk are you using?