# Unable to connect to ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195 (Connection refused)

Tags: php, codeigniter, push-notification

I've implemented Push-Notifications into my Project in Codeigniter(php) years ago and everything was working fine until 10 days ago. My `.pem` file is working fine on my local server as well as online notification tools.

*Error : "stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195 (Connection
 refused)".*

I'm using the following function:

```
public function applePushSend($deviceToken, $msg){

            $mode ='prod';

            $ctx = stream_context_create();

            if($mode=='dev'){
                $gateway = 'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195';
                stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'pushcert_dev.pem');
            }else{
                $gateway = 'ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195';
                stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'pushcert_prod.pem');
            }

            $fp = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $err, $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

            if (!$fp){
            }else{

                $alert = array();
                $alert['title'] = "My Message";
                $alert['body'] = $msg;
                $body['aps']['alert'] = $alert;
                $body['aps']['badge'] = 1;
                $body['aps']['sound'] = 'default';
                $body['notificationtypeid'] = 4;

                $payload = json_encode($body);
                $msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;
                $pushresult = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));
            }
            fclose($fp);
            return($pushresult);
        }
```

Comment: Is it possible that your certificate has expired? This has instructions on how to check it using a .pem file: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21297853/how-to-determine-ssl-cert-expiration-date-from-a-pem-encoded-certificate

Comment: Only check the pem file path, and the port is on.

Answer (score 0):

I change the code to:

```
$streamContext = stream_context_create(array('ssl' => array(
                      'local_cert' => $this->_sProviderCertificateFile
                    )));
```

The it works out like a charm!