# Git clone use gitlab self-signed CA throws error: requested domain name does not match the server's certificate

Tags: git, gitlab, ssl-certificate

As I have already known by some people's suggest, diable **http.sslVerify** is a bad idea, and according to some post, the best practice is to add the gitlab server CA to local, so I tried it in different ways:

1. Add the CA file path to git config

> ```
> git config --global http.sslCAInfo /home/yp/git-certs/rd.crt
> git clone https://10.xx.xx.xx/xxDepart/xxProject.git
> ```

2. Directly git clone with CA file path carried:

> ```
> GIT_SSL_CAINFO=/home/yp/git-certs/rd.crt git clone https://10.xx.xx.xx/xxDepart/xxProject.git
> ```

But both ways give me the same error:
**Unable to communicate securely with peer: requested domain name does not match the server's certificate.**
I think it's maybe a gitlab server issue or CA problem instead of a local git configuration error. Does anyone met this kinds of issue before, and can share the solution?
I am using an CentOS7.6 server and git version is 2.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try and [display the SAN (Subject Alternative Name) of your certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20983612/6309)

```
openssl x509 -text -noout -in cert.pem \
        -certopt no_subject,no_header,no_version,no_serial,no_signame,no_validity,no_issuer,no_pubkey,no_sigdump,no_aux
```

If it does not include your IP address, the certificate won't be considered valid.