# How could two websites be corelated when their SSL certificate return the same fingerprint?

Tags: ssl, hash, cryptography, ssl-certificate

Consider we have two or more websites which return an identical SHA-1 and SHA-256 fingerprint hash from their SSL certificate.
Could we say with a 100% assurance that the two websites are actually owned by a single individual or entity?

Comment: This seems better suited for [cryptography stack exchange](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/), as it does not seem to have anything directly to do with programming.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about cryptography and is better suited to security.SE or crypto.SE.

Comment: note that you can use Subject Alternative Name (SAN) entries in a certificate to "share" a certificate between multiple "websites". https://stackoverflow.com/a/13128918/1358308 shows how to check for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could we say with a 100% assurance that the two websites are actually owned by a single individual or entity?

Whilst not with 100% certainty, you could say with `99.999...%` repeating for a long long while.

The probability of a 2nd pre-image resistance collision on **both** hashing algorithms is **profoundly** low.

It's a 2nd pre-image resistance because we know the first websites fingerprint, ergo we are looking at the likely hood of the second website having a collision with this fingerprint.

Finding a preimage (first or second) is expected to require about `2^n` attempts, where `n` is the output size of the hashing function.

So your probability of a collision is **`1/2^256`** for SHA-256 **`*`** **`1/2^160`** for SHA-1, that said SHA-1 is not cryptographically secure, but for illustrative purposes it doesn't matter in this case.

So the chances of these two sites being owned by two different entities is about:

`1/169230328010303641331690318856389386196071598838855992136870091590247882556495704531248437872567112920983350278405979725889536`

or

```
0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005%
```

That's like 125 zeros.

It's more likely we will be wiped out by a gamma ray burst before you read this.

Comment: Note that SHA-1 has been broken, so it *doesn't* offer 160 bits of security anymore. Also, the chance of collision depends on the situation. If you can search for collisions between certs with random data in it (and that's possible) then you have to take the birthday bound in consideration, and the security of the hash functions will approximately be half that of their output size. The answer is of course still that yes, the certificates are identical because of the repeated SHA-256 fingerprint.

Comment: The break in SHA1 isn’t exploitable in a situation like this. Where is the random data for birthday attack here?

Comment: Within one of the optional fields of the certificate. Actually, unknown extensions are to be ignored. It is exactly the same problem as with MD5 based certificates, so you can see this is not a problem that should be overlooked.